# How to compile the Google Courgette tool?

Tags: google-chrome, compilation, chromium, gyp, binary-diff

Courgette ([description](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/software-updates-courgette), [source](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/courgette/)) is a Google tool that is used to update Chrome efficiently.

It seems like a great and easy-to-use tool, but I cannot manage to compile it. I've tried VS2010, GYP and using a C++ compiler directly but all has failed.

Does anybody have any advice on how to compile Courgette?

Comment: [@Mehrdad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541686/mehrdad) has successfully compiled Courgette on Windows, and has shared the binary [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32369783/2688027).

Answer (score 10):

At least, you may follow an official Google guide on [how to get compiled](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows) the whole Chromium. But instead of calling `ninja -C out/Debug chrome`, you can build only courgette: `ninja -C out/Debug courgette`. Or, if you insist on VS way of things - find the courgette project inside the Chromium project tree and "Build" it.