# How to quantitatively evaluate the difference of binary?

Tags: binary, diff, elf, portable-executable, binary-diff

I know some binary diff tool like VBinDiff and others.

Currently I have a large number of binary, around 500.

So I am looking for a binary tool to quantitatively evaluate the 
difference of binaries..

Like evaluate the 
difference of binary 10 and binary 100 is 56%.
Difference of binary 50 and binary 200 is 78%.

Is there any tool like this? ELF and PE related are both welcomed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Courgette from the chromium project](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/software-updates-courgette)
Here is a related question with source link & compilation instructions:
[How to compile Google Courgette tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542591/how-to-compile-google-courgette-tool)

Answer (score 0):

The most popular tool to do this is [bindiff](http://www.zynamics.com/bindiff.html) by zynamics. I am not sure if it is available anymore.

The other option is [Darungrim](http://www.darungrim.org/). It is free and the source is also available. You will still have to write some code atop these tools to get your desired result.