# Google courgette compiled binary for windows

Tags: windows, diff

I've been using bsdiff and i'm very happy with it, and I want to try Google's Courgette.

It seems like a large effort to fetch/compile the entire Chromium project just to get that binary out.

Does anyone know of a compiled version I can test out, or a fork that's easier to get?

Comment: I can get latest, build it and upload it for you, would that be acceptable? The Courgette portion of the Chromium source control tree is stable and complete so it won't be out of date in a day or two. Or did you want someone to add a build file to the project and store the Courgette.exe binary in SVN?

Comment: @JeremyThompson, "I can get latest, build it and upload it for you", that would be prefect. If you have a choice for 32/64 bit, i'd want both. I hope you can still answer so I can award.

Answer (score 6):

*I've tried all last night and today, grrhhhhh:(*

You can download Courgette src (without the entire Chromium) https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/courgette/+/master and then use GN and Ninja to build it (on a Win7 x64 with VS2013 SP4). However I followed the instructions exactly and kept getting errors.

It might be easier to email these guys requesting a copy: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/dDUDnc9wXts or [the new people who have taken ownership](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/courgette/+/227a2ffc8856bbec3e74241e5397037f12350a99)

I too am now determined to get Courgette.exe or be able to build it!

## Update - here's a binary

Thanks to [a StackOverflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541686), you can find [**here**](https://s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/jeremythompson.net/Rocks/courgette64.exe) a copy of the 64-bit version of Courgette compiled on 2018-08-12 with this SHA256: `5cb2843588d2cbd9f0f558e7c6c3f86bf6b2ca249bfd6c452d742f5a724471be`.
Disclaimer, run at your own risk. Use a VM and check the SHA.

For Linux and Mac users, [another user](https://github.com/rgov/courgette-build) has made a build script available on GitHub to automate the process.
Again, disclaimer: we have not vetted this; examine the code before you run it.

<sub>Hopefully this will reduce the  bandwidth of the internet significantly... in the many years to come... when file sizes get ridiculously large for simple updates. Thxs Google!</sub>

Comment: Hey Jeremy have you made any progress with this?

Comment: @user541686 - I've just moved my site over to AWS, give me 24 hrs to fix, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to compile the entire Chromium project to build Courgette. You may follow the official [Google guide](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows) on how to get the whole Chromium compiled. But instead of saying `ninja -C out\Debug chrome` you can always say :

```
ninja -C out/Debug courgette
```

to get only courgette project built.

Comment: Indeed, the very last part of the compile is an easy change, but there are still an alarming amount of steps to get there. I'm looking more for a "download binary link".

Comment: What I mean is, apart for this answer, which is elaborate, is there any other shorter method?

Comment: This is answer is just a copy of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20032386/495455

Comment: @JeremyThompson, indeed, and that's what I am hoping to avoid.