# How to build Courguette in Debian

Tags: compilation, diff, gyp, ninja

Right now I am trying to compile Courguette in order to generate a diff patch. The source and some documentation can be found in the following link:
[Courguette](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/software-updates-courgette)

I downloaded it but I don't find the way of compiling it.
I have Googled and found some references even to this forum, such as:
[StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542591/how-to-compile-google-courgette-tool)

And other references:
[Chromium Linux build instructions](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_build_instructions.md)

After reading things about ninja and gpy I decided to install them, but there are not references to a .ninja file. I find a courguette.gyp file but using gpy I neither get it compiled...

I am following the guide they provide:
Installed the depot_tools and added to the path.
gclient runhooks
gclient sync

And when I execute gn gen out/Default it fails with the following message:
gn.py: Could not find gn executable at: ~/binary_diff_tools/courgette-master/courgette/buildtools/linux64/gn

Then I used git to pull from the repository the buildtools, but I get the same result.

Any help will be appreciated.

Best regards,

Iván

Answer (score 0):

Ok... It seems that is needed to install all Chromium dependencies before being able to compile courgette so... it must be done as follows:

1. [Install depot_tools](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools_tutorial.html#_setting_up) git clone and you will have them installed.
2. After including the depot_tools in your patch (.profile or .bashsrc for example as indicate the depot_tools installation tutorial) execute fetch chromium ouside the depot_tools folder ( it always failed me when I executed it inside the same folder).
3. I want to build it in Debian so I have to do "gclient runhooks" instead of the .sh script for Ubuntu.
4. ninja -C out/Default courgette
5. You will find the executable in the folder out/Default, so ./courgette and it will indicate you the right parameters in order to generate your patch properly.

Best regards,

Iván.