# How to Update a certain file in HTML5 to exe conversion

Tags: html, exe

I am converting HTML5 file to .exe using HTML EXECUTABLES converter. After converting to exe, the total size  comes around 70 to 80MB. So the problem is when i update a single CSS file I have to convert the whole project again to a exe and give it to my Client and every time i have to upload 80MB file for very small changes.
 Is there any other alternate option to update a certain file instead of converting again to exe.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the converter is just creating a zip file with executable archiver: The answer is no.

There are tools however, that let you create a binary path for 2 files, so that you only have to transfer the diff of both. You would however have to create the new EXE and then diff it to the old one for that. So that does not help you too much. Stuff like that is usually done if you handle files in the gigabyte range.

See here for some hints for that: [How do I create binary patches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945075/how-do-i-create-binary-patches)

Or you might try the customer service of your tool, maybe they have an idea: http://www.htmlexe.com/contact

Comment: Thank you So much.Do you know any converter creating a zip file with executable archiver