# Directly Replacing Text in Binary File

Tags: string, grep, binary, executable

I have a compiled executable (binary) file - `mybin` - which `grep` indicates contains a positive match with a given text string - `Cats`.

```
grep “Cats” mybin
Binary file mybin matches
```

If I use the `-a` flag with `grep`, I can now see the actual match:

```
grep -a “File” mybin
<lots of text> (QString)Cats <lots of text>
```

Just to be clear, this is not a plain text string within the binary file i.e. I cannot see it if I open the file with a text editor.

What I want to do is replace occurrences of the string `Cats` within the binary file with the string `Bear` and keep the executable as a working executable.

How do I do this without changing it in the source code and recompiling the binary? Is such an operation even possible without corrupting the executable file and its operation?

If it is possible:

1. How would do I do it?
2. Are there any pitfalls I need to be aware of, for example the replacement string must be the same length as the original string (e.g. `Cats` -> `Bear` is ok but `Cats` -> `Dragons` is not).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks promising https://stackoverflow.com/a/56858845/2836621

Comment: Interesting. I hadn’t thought of it as a patch but I guess it is. I was kind of thinking of it like a sed command

Comment: You might want to tag this with whatever shell and OS you're running on. If you're on Unix you may also be better off asking it at https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've just posted the question there too

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, just use perl which works happily with binary files:

```
perl -pi -e 's/Cats/Dragons/g' mybin
```

or

```
perl -pi -e 's/Cats/Dragons/' mybin
```

or

```
sed 's/43617473/447261676f6e/g' original_binary > patched_binary
```

In this command, "43617473" is the hexadecimal representation of "Cats", and "447261676f6e" is the hexadecimal representation of "Dragon". Adjust these values based on your specific case.

```
perl -pi -e 's/Cats/Dragons/s' original_binary > patched_binary
```

Comment: Depending on the specific binary file, you may need to recalculate the data size or update certain checksums during the hex patching process.

Comment: It is *highly* likely that you will need to EXACTLY match the bytecount. `s/Cats/Bear/` might be fine, but `Cats` -> `Dragons` will probably throw off the offsets of a compiled file and break it.

Comment: if Dragons doesn't work, try to upload the file to a pastebin and we could look further :)

Comment: try it even with : https://bined.exbin.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just

```
sed -i 's/Cats/Bear/' mybin
```

Compare afterwards to verify.
`cmp` will tell you the exact byte offset, and you can tell it to skip a number of bytes to compare everything after:

```
$: cmp -b d272acf4-bacb-46e4-9f28-6f3b7dc1a93b.tmp x # change starts at 529
d272acf4-bacb-46e4-9f28-6f3b7dc1a93b.tmp x differ: byte 529, line 1 is 144 d 103 C

$: cmp -b -i531  d272acf4-bacb-46e4-9f28-6f3b7dc1a93b.tmp x # last changed byte at 532
d272acf4-bacb-46e4-9f28-6f3b7dc1a93b.tmp x differ: byte 1, line 1 is 105 E 163 s

$: cmp -b -i532  d272acf4-bacb-46e4-9f28-6f3b7dc1a93b.tmp x # the rest ok
```

My test file changed exactly four bytes - nothing before or after.